# HOw can i start IDM Internet download manager queue on window restart

Tags: windows-xp, download-manager

I am downloading files with IDM. My problem is when my computer restrats the i have manually click on start queue to start downloading files.

Is there any way or setting so that when my computer reboots , then IDM automatically starts downloading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on Main Download Queue -> Edit Queue -> Start Download on IDM startup.

[image]

To ensure IDM starts on Windows startup click on Download -> Options -> Launch IDM on startup

[image]